# Multiple tomcat instances using Chef

Tags: windows, tomcat, chef-infra

I have created a cookbook that will install Java and Tomcat on a Windows server. I am able to install Tomcat as a Windows service and start it. I now need to have multiple Tomcat services running on different ports on the same server. Can you please help me understand what would be the best approach to do this? I'd like to reuse the existing cookbook code to install multiple Tomcat services. I currently have 2 resources - 1 for Java and 1 for Tomcat, 1 role and 1 recipe. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add idempotent to your cookbook, which means that when ever you ran chef-client , the tomcat instance will be created , for these kind of situations we use

> not if 
>   check this below code

```
execute 'install-mysql' do
command "mv #{node['mysql']['data_dir']} #{node['mysql']['ec2_path']}"
not_if do FileTest.directory?(node['mysql']['ec2_path']) end
```

This code's execution is controlled by not_if